# AngularJS Convert Array to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have an array containing 3 elements

```
var a = [];
  a["username"]=$scope.username;
  a["phoneNo"]=$scope.phoneNo;
  a["altPhoneNo"]=$scope.altPhoneNo;
```

Now, I want to send this data to server in JSON format. Therefore, I used

```
    var aa = JSON.stringify(a);
    console.log("aa = "+aa);
```

But the console displays empty array

```
aa = []
```

How can I convert this array into JSON?

Comment: Though the console displays [], `a` does contain all the items. Just change `var a = [];` to `var a = {};`

Comment: JSON Arrays don't support named keys; just numbered indices. So, they can't be included in the string. You can however use named keys with `Object`s -- `var a = {};`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not the correct way to add elements to an array, you're adding properties instead.
If you did `console.log(a.username);` you'd see your `$scope.username` value.

You could either do

```
var a = [];
a.push({"username": $scope.username});
a.push({"phoneNo": $scope.phoneNo});
a.push({"altPhoneNo": $scope.altPhoneNo});
```

But it looks more like what you're trying to do is

```
var a = {};
a["username"] = $scope.username;
a["phoneNo"] = $scope.phoneNo;
a["altPhoneNo"] = $scope.altPhoneNo;
```

That is, you want your `a` to be an object if you're going to add properties to it.
And that would be better written as

```
var a = {};
a.username = $scope.username;
a.phoneNo = $scope.phoneNo;
a.altPhoneNo = $scope.altPhoneNo;
```